# Perforce :Not able to create new changeList with Description

Tags: perforce

Not able to create new changeList for a file/files with Description

```
p4 --field Files=E:\MyFolder\run.py --field Description=Test change -o | p4 change -i
```

Shows error
Error in change specification.
Can't include file(s) not already opened.
Open new files with p4 add, p4 edit, etc.

Cant do it in single command, wanted automate.

Answer (score 3):

Like the error says, you can't include files that aren't already open.  To create an empty changelist, do:

```
p4 --field Description=Test change -o | p4 change -i
```

If you want to open the file for edit and submit it, you don't need to create a changelist explicitly.  Just do:

```
p4 edit E:\MyFolder\run.py
(make changes?)
p4 submit -d Test
```

If you want to create a changelist that contains that file, you can take advantage of the fact that a newly created changelist will by default take ownership of files in the default changelist:

```
p4 edit E:\MyFolder\run.py
p4 --field Description=Test change -o | p4 change -i
```

If you have an empty changelist and files open in another changelist, you can move them over with the "reopen" command:

```
p4 reopen -c CHANGE E:\MyFolder\run.py
```

Note that this requires you to know the actual change number (`CHANGE`).

Finally, IFF the file is already open in the default changelist and you want to make a new changelist that contains that file and only that file, you can do this by specifying the file's **depot path** in the `Files` field of the changelist:

```
p4 --field Description=Test --field Files=//depot/run.py change -o | p4 change -i
```

A changelist description's `Files` field must contain the fully qualified depot path of each file, and it's only valid to include files there that are already open.

If you don't know the depot path of the open file, you can get it by running a command like `p4 opened`, which will list all open files by their depot paths.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. there may other files in default CLN or default CLN may contain other files sets. but I wanted ChangeList with with only 1 file.

Comment: that's good additional context, I'll add some more snippets to my answer :)